# How can get popup form values in component in Angular,material?

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material

I made a datatable with 'ADD' and 'EDIT' options. If user click add-button one pop up will come. It will ask for element name and symbol. The user clicks a save button.
I'm not getting form value in component and in the datatable we have an edit option. If the user clicks the edit button of a particular row, element name and symbol should show in the same popup. As of now, this is not working anyone helps me out to move forward.

Below is my 1st screen you can able to see data table with add and edit button

[image]

if user press ADD button this popup will come with two dropdowns here when user click Add button I'm not getting selected value

Expecting two things

1. When the user clicks ADD I should get selected dropdown values in component
2. When the user clicks Edit button I should get element name and element symbol in the same popup

[Demo](https://angular-talrct.stackblitz.io)

[project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made few changes using **`FormGroup`** in your code

```
 public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
     console.log(data);
     this.name = data.element.name;
     this.symbol = data.element.symbol;
     this.addTaskForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     name: this.name,
     symbol: this.symbol,
 });
```

**[`HERE IS THE WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-xukgmn?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)**

Comment: how to show api message in toast using angular 5 or material 2 sir?

Comment: help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927779/autocomplete-is-not-working-in-angular