# autocomplete is not working in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to do Autocomplete textbox for below data

```
Elements = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Helium' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lithium' }


  ];
```

Html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="name"
     [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (selectionChange)="elementSelectionChange($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let Element of filteredOptions | async" [value]="Element.name">
        {{ Element.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
        <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'name')">Please choose an name</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

component

```
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog implements OnInit{
  Elements = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Helium' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Lithium' }


  ];

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  selectedElementSymbol: any;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  symbol;
  //name;
  name: FormControl = new FormControl();
  id;
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  OnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.name.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filter(val))
    );
  }

  filter(val: any): any[] {
    return this.Elements.filter(Element => {
      return Element.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {


  }


}
```

This is what I built so far. autocomplete is not working but .someone help me out to move forward

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-nsjuvp?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the way you implement `OnInit` is incorrect. In your `table-basic-example.ts`, change `OnInit` to `ngOnInit` and everything will work fine.